# How to make a program create a database or something similar as a save file in c#

Tags: c#, database, saving-data

Ok, So I am trying to build a program that will allow me to make Recipe database.
The Data I am trying to save is as;

```
class RecipeDataBase
   {
      int RecipeID;
      string RecipeNames;
      string[,] Ingredients = new string[30, 30];
      string[] Steps = new string[30];
    }
```

What I am trying to get the program to do is first, it has a create new database option, this will create an empty save file in with the recipe database's name (e.g. DinnerRecipes.rdb). Then I have another form that is designed to allow the user to add recipes to whichever database they select and finally I have another one that allows the user to edit the recipes inside the database as well as lists all the current recipe names within whichever database they chose.

The Idea is so I have a program I can create almost digital cookbooks with for another program I am working on. while almost 85% of the code I know and the rest I am getting it this savefile part that I getting me.

Currently, I only have;

```
//Setting up and restricting the save system
        SaveFileDialog CRDB = new SaveFileDialog();
        CRDB.InitialDirectory = @"./";
        CRDB.RestoreDirectory = true;
        CRDB.FileName = "*.rdb";    
        CRDB.Filter = "Recipe Database |*.rdb";

        //running the save display and if they click ok creating a blank datebase.
        if (CRDB.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //This is to prep the database template for saving and creating the database file.
            RecipeDataBase recipes = new RecipeDataBase();

            Stream fileStream = CRDB.OpenFile();
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileStream);

            sw.Write(recipes);
            sw.Close();
            fileStream.Close();
        }
```

Ok, I think I might be making this more complex than it really is. however, here is an example of the data I am trying to save

```
RecipeID = 1;
RecipeNames = "Homemade Pasta Sauce";
Ingredients = ["Tomato", "Basil", "Onions", "Garlic", ect...]["4", "6 leaves or a tablespoon of ground", "3 Medium Sized", "8 clove(minced)", ect..];    
Steps = ["Peel and seed the tomatoes and set aside.", "Chop the onion, mince the garlic, and grate half of the carrot.", "Pour the olive oil into a large stockpot over medium heat.", ect];
```

What I am worried about saving the data straight into a text file is not every recipe has the same number of ingredients or steps. I want to ensure that when loading the information I don't end up with it pulling the wrong data, I am also wanting to have the RecipeIDs easily searched.

I've spent the last three days trying to find the answer I'm looking for and I don't know if I'm asking it wrong or just not connecting the answers I am finding with my project.
Please help me Stackoverflow Kenobi Your may only hope.

Comment: You just want to save it as a text file? That's easy, there's libraries that can easily convert an instance of a class into a well understood format, like JSON. Then You can use a simple method like `System.IO.File.WriteAllText` to write it to a file. You should go ahead and give that a shot.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/307283/how-to-create-a-sql-server-database-programmatically-by-using-ado-net

Comment: However, if they don't use all of the Ingredients variables won't It will cause an error when retrieving the data? for displaying it? @mason

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "use" the Ingredients variables. And did you try it? Converting to JSON and saving to a file is two lines of code: it shouldn't take you more than a few minutes to verify the behavior.

Comment: That might do it, I will give it a go and see how it work thanks @DudeWhoWantsToLearn

Comment: Maybe this is for you: [SQLite as an application file format](https://sqlite.org/appfileformat.html)

Comment: @mason I've just edited my post with what I hope will clear up what I'm trying to say. I've been at the is most of the day so I'm probably not in the clearest of minds right now.

Comment: @Fildor I will have a look at that as well as that looks like it might help however I might be a little while reading it. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should serialize your data to a format you can save, typically either a JSON or XML string or a binary format such as protobuff or MessagePack. More details on serialization can be found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/

and

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/basic-serialization

You may have to alter your classes - for example adding default constructors or the `[Serializable]` attribute.

Some examples of serialization (from the links):

Binary:

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject();  
obj.n1 = 1;  
obj.n2 = 24;  
obj.str = "Some String";  
IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();  
Stream stream = new FileStream("MyFile.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);  
formatter.Serialize(stream, obj);  
stream.Close();
```

JSON:

```
string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(weatherForecast);
File.WriteAllText(fileName, jsonString);
```

Comment: I will have a go at this after reading the links you have provided.
I will update you on with I can get it to work for what I'm trying or if I get my head in a twist.